# Why won’t the images automatically size when I upload them from the Django site

Tags: html, css, django, templates, image-scaling

I’m new and don’t know CSS. I used a template on my Django site.
When I add image links directly on the html page, they automatically size into the picture grid.
However, when I add code and upload the pictures from the website, they all display with different sizes.
I want them all consistent and fitting the pre-determined box size.

```
<div class="container-fixed">
  <div class="adoption1">
  <h1 class="wow fadeIn animated">Meet our Penguins</h1>
   <div class="grid-cats wow">
{% for post in posts %}
         <div class="col-md-4 thumbs">
           <a href="">
            <figure class="effect-marley">
                <img src="{{ post.image2.url }}" alt=""/>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>SUPER<span>CUTE</span></h2>
                    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
                    </figcaption>
            </figure>
            </a>
         </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to resize the image size override your model save method

```
from PIL import Image
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super().save(*args,**kwargs)
    img = Image.open(self.image2.path)
    if img.height>your_max_height or img.width>your_max_width:
        out_size =(your_desired_height ,your_desired_width)
        img.resize(out_size)
        img.save(self.image2.path)
```